# How can I run simple f# program on Mac OS

Tags: f#, mono, xamarin

I have installed Xamarin to study F# and write a simple program:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main args = 
    printfn "%d" 10
    0
```

If I launch it from Xamarin Studio all works fine.  But if I try to compile and run it from console I get the error:

```
$ fsharpc some.fs
F# Compiler for F# 3.1 (Open Source Edition)
Freely distributed under the Apache 2.0 Open Source License

# demas at MacBook-Air-demas.local in ~/temporary [17:47:22]
$ ./some.exe
zsh: exec format error: ./some.exe
```

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
mono some.exe
```

Or with full path:

```
/usr/bin/mono ./some.exe
```

http://www.mono-project.com/archived/guiderunning_mono_applications/